# Power button long press screen

Tags: screen

On android devices, when you hold the power button for a couple of seconds, a screen pops up with options like flight mode, silent mode, restart, power off. Is there a name for this screen?

Comment: Power button menu

Comment: It would be beneficial to follow up with a comment after a downvote.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје yes, thank you. Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu you get when long press power button is called "power button menu" or "power menu"